# DocuSign recpient unable to add agent Manage envelope

Tags: salesforce, agent, docusignapi

So I would like to add two recipients, first one without a role but but with signer type/action Manage envelope. So idea is that this person is not a signer, he would just add another person's email address.
So it would look something like this

```
'FirstName~' + somestring + ';LastName~' + somestring  + ';SignerType~ManageEnvelope,Email~' + somestring  + ';RoutingOrder~2;';
```

So this is what i need to acomplish in code - There are two recipient Actions that indicate a recipient is a reviewer; Manage envelope and Address recipients.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if all 7 recipient types are supported through the DfS (DocuSign for Salesforce) integration, but if so I'm wondering if `agent` or `intermediaries` would work as the recipient type.  I think "Manage Envelope" is what an agent does but the actual name of the recipient type is `agent`.

Looking at the DocuSign API Documentation it looks like the available recipient types through the API (not necessarily all available through DfS) are:

1. agents
2. carbonCopies
3. certifiedDeliveries
4. editors
5. inPersonSigners
6. intermediaries
7. signers

See more on [this page](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Agent%20Recipient.htm) describing the Agent type.

And [this page](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Recipient%20Parameter.htm) describes all recipient types available through the REST API.